# copy a sprite pointer to keep him const?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have this function :

```
-(void)blink:(CCSprite *)sprite

{
    CCSprite *blinker=[sprite copy]; // i have add that to prevent sprite from change.
```

it gets a sprite and do animation on it, but `sprite` is keep changing all time cause its a pointer, so my function keep get a different sprites -WHICH I DONT WANT.

i was trying to copy it to another ccsprite, but its crashes.
whats wrong here ?
is that because i havnt release it ?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code where call the blink method?
Maybe you can try this:

```
-(void) blink:(CCSprite*)sprite {
    [sprite retain];
    // Do some stuff with the sprite here
    [sprite release];
}
```

However, functions should be called with thread-safe parameters so they don't get deallocated during the functions execution.